# Python tkinter code stops working

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am working on a roulette code in python with tkinter. I am pretty far with it. But the problem is that after a few Rolls it starts bugging out and crashes. (I know its not a too good code and there are quite a lot of unnecessary steps in it, I am still pretty new to programming).

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox


root = Tk()
import random

money2 = StringVar()
varblack = StringVar()
vargreen = StringVar()
varred = StringVar()

numlist = [7]
newnumlist = [1]

def num():
    global numlist
    number = random.randint(1,15)
    if num.counter == 10:
       numlist.append(number)
    num.counter +=1
    return numlist[len(numlist) - 1]

def newnumone():
    global newnumlist
    newnumber = random.randint(1, 4)
    if newnumone.counter == 10:
       newnumlist.append(newnumber)
    newnumone.counter += 1
    return newnumlist[len(newnumlist) - 1]

newnumone.counter = 0   
num.counter = 0
RollList = ['red', 'black', 'red','black', 'red', 'black','red', 'green', 'black', 'red','black', 'red', 'black', 'red', 'black']

def colorsone():
    newList = RollList[::-1]
    if newList[0:9] == ['red', 'black', 'red','black', 'red', 'black','red', 'black', 'red']:
       RollList.append('green')
    if newList[0] == 'red':
      RollList.append('black')
    if newList[0] == 'black':
       RollList.append('red')

def lol():
    i = 0
    global RollList
    if lol.counter == 0:
       num.counter = 10
       newnumone.counter = 10
       RollList = RollList[0:15]
    number = int(num())
    newnum = int(newnumone())
    newRollsList = RollList[::-1]
    if newRollsList[0] == 'red':
       colorbgo1 = 'red'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[0] == 'green':
       colorbgo1 = 'green'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('red')
    if newRollsList[0] == 'black':
       colorbgo1 = 'black'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('green')
    if newRollsList[1] == 'red':
       colorbgo2 = 'red'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[1] == 'green':
       colorbgo2 = 'green'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[1] == 'black':
       colorbgo2 = 'black'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[2] == 'red':
       colorbgo3 = 'red'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[2] == 'green':
       colorbgo3 = 'green'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[2] == 'black':
       colorbgo3 = 'black'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[3] == 'red':
       colorbgo4 = 'red'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[3] == 'green':
       colorbgo4 = 'green'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[3] == 'black':
       colorbgo4 = 'black'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[4] == 'red':
       colorbgo5 = 'red'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[4] == 'green':
       colorbgo5 = 'green'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[4] == 'black':
       colorbgo5 = 'black'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[5] == 'red':
       colorbgo6 = 'red'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[5] == 'green':
       colorbgo6 = 'green'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[5] == 'black':
       colorbgo6 = 'black'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[6] == 'red':
       colorbgo7 = 'red'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[6] == 'green':
       colorbgo7 = 'green'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[6] == 'black':
       colorbgo7 = 'black'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[7] == 'red':
       colorbgo8 = 'red'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[7] == 'green':
       colorbgo8 = 'green'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[7] == 'black':
       colorbgo8 = 'black'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[8] == 'red':
       colorbgo9 = 'red'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[8] == 'green':
       colorbgo9 = 'green'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[8] == 'black':
       colorbgo9 = 'black'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[9] == 'red':
       colorbgo10 = 'red'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[9] == 'green':
       colorbgo10 = 'green'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    if newRollsList[9] == 'black':
       colorbgo10 = 'black'
       i = i + 1
#       colors('black')
    lol.counter += 1
    colorsone()
    if lol.counter < 150:
       countdownone(1, 10)
    if lol.counter < 200 and lol.counter > 149:
       countdownone(1, 40)
    if lol.counter < 230 and lol.counter > 199:
       countdownone(1, 80)
    if lol.counter < 240 and lol.counter >229:
       countdownone(1, 140)
    if lol.counter < 250 and lol.counter > 239:
       countdownone(1, 200)
    if number == 8: 
       if lol.counter < 258 and lol.counter > 249:
          countdownone(1, 300)
       if lol.counter < 259 and lol.counter > 257:
          countdownone(1, 500)
       if lol.counter == 259:
          play()
#             lol.counter = 0   
    if number >= 9: #black    
       if newnum == 1:
          if lol.counter < 254 and lol.counter > 249:
             countdownone(1, 300)
          if lol.counter < 257 and lol.counter > 253:
             countdownone(1, 500)
          if lol.counter == 257:
#             print(1)
             play()
#             lol.counter = 0   
       if newnum == 2:
          if lol.counter < 252 and lol.counter > 249:
             countdownone(1, 300)
          if lol.counter < 255 and lol.counter > 251:
             countdownone(1, 500)
          if lol.counter == 255:
#             print(2)
             play()
#             lol.counter = 0   
       if newnum == 3:
          if lol.counter < 259 and lol.counter > 249:
             countdownone(1, 300)
          if lol.counter < 262 and lol.counter > 258:
             countdownone(1, 500) 
          if lol.counter == 262:
#             print(3)
             play()
#             lol.counter = 0   
       if newnum == 4:
          if lol.counter < 258 and lol.counter > 249:
             countdownone(1, 300)
          if lol.counter < 260 and lol.counter > 257:
             countdownone(1, 500)   
          if lol.counter == 260:
#             print(4)
             play()
#             lol.counter = 0   
    if number <= 7: #red
       if newnum == 1:
          if lol.counter < 254 and lol.counter > 249:
             countdownone(1, 300)
          if lol.counter < 256 and lol.counter > 253:
             countdownone(1, 500)
          if lol.counter == 256:
#             print(5)
             play()
#             lol.counter = 0   
       if newnum == 2:
          if lol.counter < 252 and lol.counter > 249:
             countdownone(1, 300)
          if lol.counter < 253 and lol.counter > 251:
             countdownone(1, 500)
          if lol.counter == 253:
             play()
#             print(6)
#             lol.counter = 0   
       if newnum == 3:
          if lol.counter < 256 and lol.counter > 249:
             countdownone(1, 300)
          if lol.counter < 258 and lol.counter > 255:
             countdownone(1, 500) 
          if lol.counter == 258:
#             print(7)
             play()
#             lol.counter = 0   
       if newnum == 4:
          if lol.counter < 258 and lol.counter > 249:
             countdownone(1, 300)
          if lol.counter < 261 and lol.counter > 257:
             countdownone(1, 500)   
          if lol.counter == 261:
#             print(8)
             play()
#            lol.counter = 0             

    labelRoll1 = Label(root, bg = colorbgo1, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 10, column = 4)
#    labelRollsw1 = Label(root, text = ' ').grid(row = 15, column = 4)
    labelRoll2 = Label(root, bg = colorbgo2, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 10, column = 5)
#    labelRollsw2 = Label(root, text = ' ').grid(row = 15, column = 5)
    labelRoll3 = Label(root, bg = colorbgo3, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 10, column = 6)
#    labelRollsw3 = Label(root, text = ' ').grid(row = 15, column = 6)
    labelRoll4 = Label(root, bg = colorbgo4, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 10, column = 7)
#    labelRollsw4 = Label(root, text = ' ').grid(row = 15, column = 7)
    labelRoll5 = Label(root, bg = colorbgo5, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 10, column = 8)
#    labelRollsw5 = Label(root, text = ' ').grid(row = 15, column = 8)
    labelRoll6 = Label(root, bg = colorbgo6, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 10, column = 9)
#    labelRollsw6 = Label(root, text = ' ').grid(row = 15, column = 9)
    labelRoll7 = Label(root, bg = colorbgo7, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 10, column = 10)
#    labelRollsw7 = Label(root, text = ' ').grid(row = 15, column = 10)
    labelRoll8 = Label(root, bg = colorbgo8, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 10, column = 11)
#    labelRollsw8 = Label(root, text = ' ').grid(row = 15, column = 11)
    labelRoll9 = Label(root, bg = colorbgo9, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 10, column = 12)
#    labelRollsw9 = Label(root, text = ' ').grid(row = 15, column = 12)
    labelRoll10 = Label(root, bg = colorbgo10, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 10, column = 13)


labelRollsw1 = Label(root, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 17, column = 4)
labelRollsw2 = Label(root, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 17, column = 5)
labelRollsw3 = Label(root, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 17, column = 6)
labelRollsw4 = Label(root, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 17, column = 7)
labelRollsw5 = Label(root, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 17, column = 8)
labelRollsw6 = Label(root, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 17, column = 9)
labelRollsw7 = Label(root, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 17, column = 10)
labelRollsw8 = Label(root, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 17, column = 11)
labelRollsw9 = Label(root, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 17, column = 12)
labelRollsw10 = Label(root, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 17, column = 13)    
labelRollsw11 = Label(root, height=4, width = 8).grid(row = 17, column = 14)

lol.counter = 0

def countdownone(count, i): 
#    timer['text'] = count
    if count > 0:
       root.after(i, countdownone, count-count, i)
    if count == 0:
       lol()


#timerone = Label(root)
#timerone.grid()

end = Label(root, text = '↓').grid(row = 8, column =9)
endone = Label(root, text = '↑').grid(row = 16, column =9)
#allin = Button(root, text = 'LOL', command = countdown(1, 100)).grid(row = 3, column = 3)


def countdown(count):    
    timer['text'] = count
    if count > 0:
       root.after(1000, countdown, count-1)
    if count == 3:
       countdownone(1, 10)
    if count == 20:
       entry_money.configure(state="normal")
       greenB.configure(state="normal")
       blackB.configure(state="normal")
       redB.configure(state="normal")
    if count == 0:
       entry_money.configure(state="disabled")
       greenB.configure(state="disabled")
       blackB.configure(state="disabled")
       redB.configure(state="disabled")
#   if count == 0:
#       play()


def play():
    varblack1 = varblack.get()
    vargreen1 = vargreen.get()
    varred1 = varred.get()
    if vargreen1 == 'off' and varblack1 == 'off' and varred1 == 'off':
       nothing()
    if varred1 == 'on':
#       blackB.deselect()
#       greenB.deselect()
       red()
    if varblack1 == 'on':
#       greenB.deselect()
       black()
    if vargreen1 == 'on':
       green()
    redB.deselect()
    blackB.deselect()
    greenB.deselect()
    countdown(20)
    lol.counter = 0
    entry_money.delete(0, 'end')
#    newnumone.counter = 0  
#    num.counter = 0

def all():
    total1=total.get()
    money2.set(total1)  

def red():
    money1 = money2.get()
    roulette3('red', money1)

def black():
    money1 = money2.get()
    roulette3('black', money1)

def green():
    money1 = money2.get()
    roulette3('green', money1)

def nothing():
    roulette3('no', 1)


def colors(clr):
    file = open('newfile.txt', 'a')
    file.write(clr)
    file.close()
    file = open('newfile.txt', 'r')
    file.close()
    PrevRollsColor()



def PrevRollsColor():
    lastRollsList = []
    lastRolls = open("newfile.txt", "r")
    Rolls = lastRolls.read().splitlines()
    for line in Rolls:
      lastRollsList.append(line)
    lastRolls.close()
    newRollsList = lastRollsList[::-1]
    #labelRollsList = [labelRolls2, labelRolls3, labelRolls4, labelRolls5, labelRolls6, labelRolls7, labelRolls8, labelRolls9, labelRolls10]
    if newRollsList[0] == 'red':
       colorbg1 = 'red'
    if newRollsList[0] == 'green':
       colorbg1 = 'green'
    if newRollsList[0] == 'black':
       colorbg1 = 'black'
    if newRollsList[1] == 'red':
       colorbg2 = 'red'
    if newRollsList[1] == 'green':
       colorbg2 = 'green'
    if newRollsList[1] == 'black':
       colorbg2 = 'black'
    if newRollsList[2] == 'red':
       colorbg3 = 'red'
    if newRollsList[2] == 'green':
       colorbg3 = 'green'
    if newRollsList[2] == 'black':
       colorbg3 = 'black'
    if newRollsList[3] == 'red':
       colorbg4 = 'red'
    if newRollsList[3] == 'green':
       colorbg4 = 'green'
    if newRollsList[3] == 'black':
       colorbg4 = 'black'
    if newRollsList[4] == 'red':
       colorbg5 = 'red'
    if newRollsList[4] == 'green':
       colorbg5 = 'green'
    if newRollsList[4] == 'black':
       colorbg5 = 'black'
    if newRollsList[5] == 'red':
       colorbg6 = 'red'
    if newRollsList[5] == 'green':
       colorbg6 = 'green'
    if newRollsList[5] == 'black':
       colorbg6 = 'black'
    if newRollsList[6] == 'red':
       colorbg7 = 'red'
    if newRollsList[6] == 'green':
       colorbg7 = 'green'
    if newRollsList[6] == 'black':
       colorbg7 = 'black'
    if newRollsList[7] == 'red':
       colorbg8 = 'red'
    if newRollsList[7] == 'green':
       colorbg8 = 'green'
    if newRollsList[7] == 'black':
       colorbg8 = 'black'
    if newRollsList[8] == 'red':
       colorbg9 = 'red'
    if newRollsList[8] == 'green':
       colorbg9 = 'green'
    if newRollsList[8] == 'black':
       colorbg9 = 'black'
    if newRollsList[9] == 'red':
       colorbg10 = 'red'
    if newRollsList[9] == 'green':
       colorbg10 = 'green'
    if newRollsList[9] == 'black':
       colorbg10 = 'black'


    labelRolls1 = Label(root, bg = colorbg1, height = 1, width = 2).grid(row = 18, column = 16)
    labelRollsw1 = Label(root, bg = 'white', text = ' ').grid(row = 18, column = 17)
    labelRolls2 = Label(root, bg = colorbg2, height = 1, width = 2).grid(row = 18, column = 18)
    labelRollsw2 = Label(root, bg = 'white', text = ' ').grid(row = 18, column = 19)
    labelRolls3 = Label(root, bg = colorbg3, height = 1, width = 2).grid(row = 18, column = 20)
    labelRollsw3 = Label(root, bg = 'white', text = ' ').grid(row = 18, column = 21)
    labelRolls4 = Label(root, bg = colorbg4, height = 1, width = 2).grid(row = 18, column = 22)
    labelRollsw4 = Label(root, bg = 'white', text = ' ').grid(row = 18, column = 23)
    labelRolls5 = Label(root, bg = colorbg5, height = 1, width = 2).grid(row = 18, column = 24)
    labelRollsw5 = Label(root, bg = 'white', text = ' ').grid(row = 18, column = 25)
    labelRolls6 = Label(root, bg = colorbg6, height = 1, width = 2).grid(row = 18, column = 26)
    labelRollsw6 = Label(root, bg = 'white', text = ' ').grid(row = 18, column = 27)
    labelRolls7 = Label(root, bg = colorbg7, height = 1, width = 2).grid(row = 18, column = 28)
    labelRollsw7 = Label(root, bg = 'white', text = ' ').grid(row = 18, column = 29)
    labelRolls8 = Label(root, bg = colorbg8, height = 1, width = 2).grid(row = 18, column = 30)
    labelRollsw8 = Label(root, bg = 'white', text = ' ').grid(row = 18, column = 31)
    labelRolls9 = Label(root, bg = colorbg9, height = 1, width = 2).grid(row = 18, column = 32)
    labelRollsw9 = Label(root, bg = 'white', text = ' ').grid(row = 18, column = 33)
    labelRolls10 = Label(root, bg = colorbg10, height = 1, width = 2).grid(row = 18, column = 34)   

def roulette3(color, money):
    yes = 'yes'
    no = 'no'
    on = 'yes'
    total_money = total.get()
    number = int(num())
    try:
        if color == no and money == 1:
          if number == 8:
            colors('green\n')
          if number <= 7:
            colors('red\n')
          if number >= 9:
            colors('black\n')
        if int(money) <= int(total_money) and int(money) > 0:
          if color == 'green' or color == 'red' or color == 'black':
            if number == 8:
              if color == 'green':
                total.set(int(total_money) + int(money) * 14 - int(money))
                a = ('It was green! You won!')
#                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('You won', a)
                colors('green\n')
              elif color != 'green':
                total.set(int(total_money)  - int(money))
                b = ('It was green! You lost!')
#                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('You lost', b)
                colors('green\n')
            if number <= 7:
              if color == 'red':
                total.set(int(total_money) + int(money) * 2 - int(money))
                c = ('It was red! You won!')
#                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('You won', c)
                colors('red\n')
              elif color != 'red':
                total.set(int(total_money) - int(money))
                d = ('It was red! You lost!')
#                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('You lost', d)
                colors('red\n')
            if number >= 9:
              if color == 'black':
                total.set(int(total_money) + int(money) * 2 - int(money))
                e = ('It was black! You won!')
#                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('You won', e)
                colors('black\n')
              elif color != 'black':
                total.set(int(total_money) - int(money))
                f = ('It was black! You lost!')
#                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('You lost', f)
                colors('black\n')
        else:
            g = ('you are unable to play with this amount')
#            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Wrong Amount', g)
            nothing()
    except:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Invalid Input', 'Invalid Input')
        nothing()


total = StringVar()
total.set('1000')
yourMoney = Label(root, text = 'Your Money:')
yourMoney.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

all_money = Label(root, textvariable = total)   
all_money.grid(row = 1, column = 1)


roulette = Label(root, text = 'Roulette', bg = 'red', fg = 'black')
roulette.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = N)


moneyLabel = Label(root, text = 'How much:')
entry_money = Entry(root, textvariable = money2)


moneyLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
entry_money.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

selectcolor = Label(root, text = 'Select your color:')
selectcolor.grid(row = 5, column = 0)

redB = Checkbutton(root, text = 'Red', variable = varred, onvalue = 'on', offvalue = 'off')
redB.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
blackB = Checkbutton(root, text = 'Black', variable = varblack, onvalue = 'on', offvalue = 'off')
blackB.grid(row = 5, column = 1)
greenB = Checkbutton(root, text = 'Green', variable = vargreen, onvalue = 'on', offvalue = 'off')
greenB.grid(row = 6, column = 1)

#playButton = Button(root, text = 'Play', command = play).grid(row = 4, column = 5)

#dontroll = Button(root, text = 'Wait for next Roll', command = nothing).grid(row = 3, column = 3)
lastrolls = Label(root, text = 'Last Rolls:')
lastrolls.grid(row = 18, column = 15)

zeit = Label(root, text = 'Time left until next roll:').grid(row = 1, column = 3)
timer = Label(root)
timer.grid(row = 1, column = 4)

allin = Button(root, text = 'All In', command = all).grid(row = 3, column = 3)




blackB.deselect()
greenB.deselect()
redB.deselect()

PrevRollsColor()

countdown(20)

#photo = PhotoImage(file = 'C:\\Users\\Louis\\Desktop\\roulette.png')
#label = Label(root, image=photo)
#label.grid(row = 7, column = 1)


root.geometry('1500x500+500+300')
root.title('roulette')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you only post the part where it's not working.

Comment: Well the problem is that i dont know what part isnt working. The whole program just stops working after a while...

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  The exercise of removing what is not necessary might reveal the problem to you.  What does 'start bugging out'? mean?  What is the traceback when it stops?  In many places, multiple `if` statements can and should be replaced with a dict lookup.

Comment: Well there is no Traceback. I just get a windows error that my program stopped working. With bugging out I mean that all of a sudden some of my labels are outside of my initial window. You could maybe try running it and wait for a while to see it yourself. (Maybe it is also only on my end)